# Unable to get the corect algorithm for the question

Tags: c++

Given a chess board of and n x n. A knight at `(X1,Y1)` can clash with opposite colour knight at `(X2, Y2)` if

1. `| x1 - x2| == 2 and | y1- y2| == 1`

Or

2. `|x1-x2| == 1 and | y1-y2| == 2`.

I want to arrange as many knights as possible on a chess board to maximise the clashes.

I was thinking about this question for 3 days but still can't figure out the correct algorithm for it. If someone can guide me ??

Comment: Brute force recursion is a good place to start. The second place is Wikipedia to see if there's an algorithm for this that already exists.

Comment: Don't you mean *minimize* the clashes?

Comment: I need the correct algorithm to solve this. Can you all please help me ??

Comment: @cigien: I don't think so, question is which color should have each knight (one by case). there are 2^n possibilities, brute force seems the wrong way.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you were responding to tadman. Yes, brute force is probably unwise.

Comment: I respond to both (I should have wrote 2 comments...). About your comment, filling board with only white knights will result in 0 clashes, replace 1 white by 1 black in the "center", you obtain 8 clashes. maximize seems the good meaning.

Comment: guys please help me

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I see. Maximize makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @ShekharSingh One problem is you have tagged this with C++, when this is in fact an algorithm question. Change the tags so that users who are capable of helping can see the question.